# React DateTimePicker showing required error even after select the value in datepicker

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks, react-hook-form, yup

React DateTimePicker is showing **required** error even after selecting a value in DatePicker:

```js
const validationForm = Yup.object().shape({
  DateTime:Yup.date().required('Date and time is required')
});

<DateTimePicker {...register('DateTime')}/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here the **register function from react form hook form might not support** the 3rd party library react datetimepicker.

For these types of components, we can **use the Control component from react hook form** to wrap the custom component for the validations.

For ex.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDatePicker from "react-datepicker";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";

function App() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(data => console.log(data))}>
      <Controller
        control={control}
        name="ReactDatepicker"
        render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
          <ReactDatePicker
            onChange={onChange}
            onBlur={onBlur}
            selected={value}
          />
        )}
      />
      
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

**For more information refer to the official docs from react hook form.**
[React Hook form Control](https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/)